# How to compare two xpaths in robot frame work in selenium web driver?

Tags: robotframework

I had tried the following command:

```
CLICK ELEMENT //*[@id="txtBillUniqueIdChk_Grd12597"]:://*[@id="grdFundTransfer"]/tbody/tr[13].
```

I got the error message like:

```
"Element with locator '"//*[@id="txtBillUniqueIdChk_Grd12597"]:://*[@id="grdFundTransfer"]/tbody/tr[13]"'  not found ".
```

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @resource-id instead of @id.

Answer (score -1):

Here in the above line u have given an xpath. But in that a random Id generated like '_Grd12597' it is not same for every time when u click xpath. So it throws an error'